# How to send Fragments' TextView data as message

Tags: android

I would like to have the data taken from the TextView object sent by clicking a button as SMS/Social Media/etc.  Currently I can only send a static string as SMS.

This is my current method for sending data.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
android.app.FragmentManager manager;
ViewPager viewpager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // instantiate TextView object
    //TextView textViiew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // initialize viewPager
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // create object of Adapter class
    PagerAdapter padapter = new org.example.androidsdk.demo.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);

    manager = getFragmentManager();
}

public void slideBack() {
    Fragment f1 = new Fragment();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.pager, f1, "X");

    // addToBackStack here
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}





    public void implicitSendQuote(View v) {
        String text = ((textView)v).getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "TEXT");  //  -   I want to add data from TextView here
//      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.id.textView1);
//      intent.putExtra("sms_body", R.id.textView1); 
//      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.layout.fragment_one_layout);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: When is implicitSendQuote called? Is it your button's onClick method? If it is, v will be the button, not the TextView.

Comment: implicitSendQuote is called when the button is tapped.  Yes, implicitSendQuote is the onClick method.  Please print out an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is attempting to cast a Button to a TextView, which is not what you want.

```
String text = ((textView)v).getText().toString();
```

Change it to this, which will find your TextView by id, then get the text as a string:

```
String text = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
```

And send the text to your intent:

```
intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
```

Comment: This worked out well - Thanks!  Now what if I wanted to use the text from each particular Fragment rather than explicitly using 'texView1'?  How can I use the TextView object from each particular Fragment?

Comment: you could do something along the lines of `fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)` to get a reference to a particular element in the fragment's view

Answer (score 1):

`implicitSendQuote` will be passed the View for the button that is calling it as an XML defined onClick.  To get the text from your TextView, you will probably want to make the textView a member variable rather than a local variable when you find it in onCreate().  Then, get the text from in in your onClick like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
android.app.FragmentManager manager;
ViewPager viewpager;
TextView textView;//textView should be a member variable so you can access it later.


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); //find textView
...
}

public void implicitSendQuote(View v) {
        String text = textView.getText().toString(); //get value of textView when button is clicked.
...
intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
...
}
```

You can then get this text in your next activity via `getIntent().getStringExtra("sms_body");`

Incidentally, it is good practice to make this string key a static member of one of the activities, i.e.:

```
public class NextActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     public static final String SMS_BODY = "sms_body";

     protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
          String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(SMS_BODY);
     }
}
```

And in onImplicitSendQuote:

```
intent.putExtra(NextActivity.SMS_BODY, text);
```

This way, you are only defining the string in one place, so if you change it later, it won't become incompatible between activities.

Comment: How would I pass the 'text' object into the message?

Comment: `intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);`

Comment: I created a new Activity 'NextActivity', declared the SMS_BODY variable as a public member and 'text' variable to the 'onCreate' method.  I am getting an compile error "get intent cannot be resolved".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Likely, you were missing the perentheses after getIntent() which I neglected to type.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

with:

```
String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString());
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem is the absence of cast.

Get `TextView`by id:

```
String text = (String) ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.yourTextView)).getText();
```

or as @emersso said, using a attribute to store your text `TextView`

Comment: I am now able to pull the text from a particular TextView.  I would like to send the text from whichever fragment is currently active.  How can I send the text from the current/active fragment?